# How to update database on remote ms sql server (EF Code First)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

While developing an application I used EF automatic migrations. So now when I have deployed my app on VPS, I don't know how to add new tables and fields to my database.

Can I connect to the remote database directly from my project in VS2012, updating a connection string, and update the database using "update-database" in package manager console? Or do I need to install VS on my VPS and update the database from VPS?

My database is already filled with data, so I can't delete it and create again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can use Visual Studio, follow [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/17/creating-a-database-connection-to-a-remote-sql-server-database-within-visual-web-developer.aspx) - it should work for VS 2012 too.
You can also use [Code first Migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) to update your model by using this command in package manager console:

```
Update-Database
```

and you can specify your connection string name:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionStringName "MyConnectionString"
```

Comment: thank you! I have difficulties with remote access to the server. Can I use "Update-Database -Script" and then manually run the script on the sql server?

Comment: [this link](http://robertgreiner.com/2012/05/using-entity-framework-database-migrations-to-update-a-remote-database/) can be helpful

Comment: Take care because this way you're not running your Seed.

Comment: Thanks @SirwanAfifi through whom I learnt about -StartUpProjectName. That was it for me. Despite having selected the right project in the dropdown it ran the seed with god knows which config file.

Comment: It seems it isn't working anymore... `Update-Database: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionStringName'.`

Answer (score 4):

This is best explained in the link below.  Read the "Getting a SQL script" section.  That will explain how to generate a script which you can then run on your target database.

This will be necessary if your database access is IP protected for example.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: Summary of link: use this line at startup of app: `Database.SetInitializer(
                new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());`